# How to handle cancelation Google or Facebook sign in?

Tags: flutter, authentication

I'm trying to handle when user cancel modal window.

```
try {
      user = await _googleSignIn
          .signIn()
          .catchError((onError) => print('onError'));
      
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception handled.');
      print(e);
}
```

But try catch not handling error

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_canceled, com.google.GIDSignIn, The user canceled the sign-in flow., null))

Comment: You catch error in `catchError` callback, your exception doesn't handled in `catch`.

Comment: CatchError also not handling

Comment: Where you are getting error?